# How to trigger ng-click inside ng-repeat angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

ng-click does not work inside ng-repeat. I have read all the guides and similar questions, but nothing work in my code. If I click on the  tag inside the ng-repeat nothing happen, but if I click on my button the function is called.

**html**

```
                <div ng-repeat="sykdom in sykdommer" ng-model="sykdom.name" ng-click="test();"> 
                     <a class="item item-icon-right" href="#" ng-click="test();" >
                        {{sykdom.name}}
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>
                     </a>   
                </div>  
<button ng-click="test()> test </button>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.sykdommer = [{name:'test1'},
                     {name:'test2'},
                     {name:'test3'}];

$scope.test = function(){
    alert('you clicked!');
};
```

I have tried with ng-click="$parent.test()" and ng-model="sykdom.name" without any luck. Please help, really stuck on this problem :(

Comment: could you please create a plunkr or fiddle with issue? does `ng-repeat` div is inside `ng-include` or `ng-if` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example i've made with your data: http://plnkr.co/edit/o4sqPd

Template should be like:

```
<div ng-repeat="sykdom in sykdommer"> 
      <a class="item item-icon-right" href="#" ng-click="test(sykdom.name);" >
         {{sykdom.name}}
       <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>
      </a>   
</div>
```

You should use **ng-model** directive only in case if it's a part of you changeable data - in input/textarea etc. tags (documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Comment: I tried the original code in a plunker, it works as is; I will not downvote your answer, because you spent time on this; I, however, downvoted the question; working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/StkhSt7jVqFUtQpTUNwu?p=preview

Comment: @shershen did you able to reproduce the issue? why was that happening?

Comment: @Manube yes you're right, I've first made edits to ng-model, that i've mentioned in my answer. And actually yes, original setup seems to work as well, so the problem is not in this part seems to be

Comment: Thanks, yes it actually works. I now see what my problem was, I added some animation to the div, which caused the error. Don't really know why, but thanks!